# vuepress2: how to get Vue instance so I can use third part vue plugin?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuepress

I am trying to use [v-wave](https://github.com/justintaddei/v-wave) in [VuePress 2](https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/) (the VuePress powered by Vue 3)

I followed the docs, try to use the `v-wave` as a local plugin of the `VuePress 2`

`.vuepress/config.js`

```js
const vwave = require('path/to/v-wave.js');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        (options, app) => {
            app.use(vwave); // the `app` is a instance of VuePress not Vue
            return {name: 'v-wave'};
        }
    ]
};
```

But it didn't work, because the `app` isn't the Vue instance but the VuePress.

How can I install `v-wave` to make it work in VuePress 2?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's no config API in VuePress specifically to configure the client app. However, the Plugin API supports configuring a root component in the client app with the [`clientAppRootComponentFiles` property](https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/reference/plugin-api.html#clientapprootcomponentfiles).

For example, this config points to `.vuepress/RootComponent.vue`:

```js
// .vuepress/config.js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      name: 'root-component-setup',
      clientAppRootComponentFiles: path.resolve(__dirname, './RootComponent.vue'),
    }
  ]
}
```

In that component file, use the Composition API's `getCurrentInstance()` to access the application instance's [`use()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#use) to globally install the `v-wave` plugin:

```html
// .vuepress/RootComponent.vue
<template>
  <slot></slot>
</template>

<script>
import { getCurrentInstance, defineComponent } from 'vue'
import VWave from 'v-wave'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    getCurrentInstance().appContext.app.use(VWave)
  }
})
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuepress-app-plugin?file=docs%2F.vuepress%2Fconfig.js)